# minGW: "No rule to make target"

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I realize this type of question has been asked earlier, however I looked everywhere and I couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to invoke a makefile using minGW's make utility, however I keep running into this error:

> D:\Aufgabe 4>mingw32-make -f
>   aufgabe4.make
>   mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target `half_adder.o,', needed by`aufgabe4.out'. Stop.'

This is the content of the makefile:

```
aufgabe4.out : half_adder.o, adder.o, program.o
    g++ -o aufgabe4.out half_adder.o adder.o program.o

half_adder.o: half_adder.h half_adder.cpp
   g++ -c half_adder.cpp

adder.o: half_adder.h half_adder.cpp adder.h adder.cpp
   g++ -c adder.cpp

program.o: half_adder.h adder.h program.cpp
   g++ -c program.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o aufgabe4.out
```

This is the content of the directory:

```
D:\Aufgabe 4>dir
Volume in drive D has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 6E0B-16A3

Directory of D:\Aufgabe 4

11/08/2011  12:29 PM    <DIR>          .
11/08/2011  12:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/08/2011  12:02 PM               381 adder.cpp
11/08/2011  11:52 AM                88 adder.h
11/08/2011  01:01 PM               346 aufgabe4.make
11/08/2011  11:56 AM               171 half_adder.cpp
11/08/2011  11:54 AM                78 half_adder.h
11/08/2011  12:15 PM               421 program.cpp
           6 File(s)          1,485 bytes
           2 Dir(s)   2,241,265,664 bytes free
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `adder.o` really depending on `half_adder.cpp`? If `adder.cpp` only includes the `half_adder.h` file, then the .cpp file is not needed in the rule.

Comment: Yes, adder.cpp relies on functions implemented in half_adder.cpp. I will remove the .cpp file from the rule, as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aufgabe4.out : half_adder.o, adder.o, program.o
```

Remove the commas.

```
aufgabe4.out : half_adder.o adder.o program.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove "," from the first makefile line.

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your Makefile is badly written. Modify it to this:

```
aufgabe4.out : half_adder.o adder.o program.o
```

You can't use comma to separate the targets. Use spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

Your make is probably a [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/), you might debug it using `make --debug=b`